# Why are "in (dimension)" measurements used?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

The rock is six feet *in height*.   The rock is six feet *tall*.

The rock is nine feet *in width*.   The rock is nine feet *wide*.

The rock is ten tons *in weight*.   The rock *weighs* ten tons.

I don't understand why the "in" forms are used. They seem pretentious, and they add words to no purpose. Does anyone know why "in" isn't out?

Comment: There's no rule that we _have_ to express everything in the fewest possible words!

Comment: Often when a longer way of saying the same thing is chosen, it is to create an air of formality, or a storytelling feeling. Possibly because of context or possibly for emphasis.

Comment: Measurement along a general dimension  is often  expressed that way. For example, how does Smith rank?  Second *in the mile*.  For things like height, width, breadth and depth, we have *high/tall, wide, broad* and *deep*, but not every dimension corresponds to a simple adjective.

Answer (score -1):

It is an idiomatic use of the preposition “in”:

***[in height](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20height)*** (idiom)

> - having a specified height : tall

(M-W)

Comment: Saying it's idiomatic is merely saying that that's the way it's done. Saying it's an idiom is adding that there's something unusual about the fixed expression/s. But OP asks **why** this unusual type of expression has come about.